TypeScript Number Set
I originally premiered this code to the internet in this StackOverflow post, and per a recommendation through one of the comments, I am reposting it here.
I am making a floating-point number set implementation using bitwise operations (for fun of course, I have no idea if this is performant). Feel free to render thoughts, and of course check out the original post if you are interested in the question I had about it. The main class (NumberSet) is the last class in the file.
/*
 * This is pretty complicated and otherwise minimally commented so I feel as though I owe a bit of an explanation here.
 * We want an intrinsically sorted set that can contain ANY valid JS number. So we first convert the number into bytes,
 * by sharing an ArrayBuffer between a Uint8Array and Float64Array. Then we use the first 7 bytes, going from MSB to
 * LSB, to traverse through a tree until we find the "ByteSet" that defines the values within the set for the
 * last 8 bits. An optimization is also implemented where if it is known that all bytes after the one represented by
 * the current node being traversed are 0, the presence of that exact number within the set is stored in that node
 * and NO children are made. This takes advantage of the fact that integers in IEEE754 will typically end in long runs
 * of 0.
 */

/**
 * A simple set that can contain values from 0 to 255 (inclusive).
 */
class ByteSet {

    private readonly data;
    constructor() {
        // 256 bits can fit in 32 bytes
        this.data = new Uint8Array(32);
    }

    has(index: number): boolean {
        const flag = 1 << (index & 7);
        return (this.data[index >> 3] & flag) !== 0;
    }

    add(index: number): void {
        this.set(index, true);
    }

    remove(index: number): void {
        this.set(index, false);
    }

    private set(index: number, value: boolean): void {
        const flag = 1 << (index & 7);
        index >>= 3;
        if (value) {
            this.data[index] |= flag;
        } else {
            this.data[index] &= (~flag);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Iterates over this set and yields values that arise when a value in this set is inserted into ``buf8`` at
     * ``offset`` and evaluated as a float through ``buf64``. This is used by ``NumberSetNode`` to permute through
     * stored least significant bytes given the common upper 7 bytes of a float.
     */
    *iterator(buf8: Uint8Array, buf64: Float64Array, offset: number): Generator<number> {
        let head: number = -1;
        let base: number;
        let flag: number;
        while ((++head) < 32) {
            flag = this.data[head];
            if (flag === 0) continue;
            base = head << 3;
            for (let i=0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (flag & (1 << i)) {
                    buf8[offset] = (base | i);
                    yield buf64[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

/*
It is imperative that we probe the platform's endianness so that we know which byte is most significant.
*/
const IS_BIG_ENDIAN: boolean = (() => {
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(2);
    const u8 = new Uint8Array(ab);
    const u16 = new Uint16Array(ab);
    u8[0] = 0xAA;
    u8[1] = 0xBB;
    return u16[0] === 0xAABB;
})();

/*
If BE: Traverse from 0 (MSB) to 7 (LSB)
If LE: Traverse from 7 (MSB) to 0 (LSB)
*/
const TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION: 1 | -1 = IS_BIG_ENDIAN ? 1 : -1;
const TRAVERSAL_START: 0 | 7 = IS_BIG_ENDIAN ? 0 : 7;
const TRAVERSAL_END: 0 | 7 = IS_BIG_ENDIAN ? 7 : 0;

/**
 * A node in the tree of a NumberSet. This covers the general case of diverting calls to the appropriate
 * NumberSetNode or ByteSet, or using the stored value when appropriate.
 */
class NumberSetNode {

    // @ts-ignore The value IS defined in the constructor, but though invocation of clear0
    private value: boolean;
    // @ts-ignore The value IS defined in the constructor, but though invocation of clear0
    private children: { [index: number]: NumberSetNode | ByteSet };

    constructor() {
        this.clear0();
    }

    protected clear0(): void {
        this.value = false;
        this.children = {};
    }

    protected has0(bytes: Uint8Array, index: number, atWhichAllZero: number): boolean {
        if (index === atWhichAllZero) return this.value;
        const determinant: number = bytes[index];
        const child = this.children[determinant];
        if (typeof child === "undefined") return false;
        index += TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION;
        if (index === TRAVERSAL_END) {
            return (child as ByteSet).has(bytes[index]);
        } else {
            return (child as NumberSetNode).has0(bytes, index, atWhichAllZero);
        }
    }

    protected add0(bytes: Uint8Array, index: number, atWhichAllZero: number): void {
        if (index === atWhichAllZero) {
            this.value = true;
            return;
        }
        const determinant: number = bytes[index];
        let child: NumberSetNode | ByteSet = this.children[determinant];

        index += TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION;
        const isTail: boolean = (index === TRAVERSAL_END);
        if (typeof child === "undefined") {
            child = isTail ? new ByteSet() : new NumberSetNode();
            this.children[determinant] = child;
        }

        if (isTail) {
            (child as ByteSet).add(bytes[index]);
        } else {
            (child as NumberSetNode).add0(bytes, index, atWhichAllZero);
        }
    }

    protected remove0(bytes: Uint8Array, index: number, atWhichAllZero: number): void {
        if (index === atWhichAllZero) {
            this.value = false;
            return;
        }
        const determinant: number = bytes[index];
        const child: NumberSetNode | ByteSet = this.children[determinant];
        if (typeof child === "undefined") return;

        index += TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION;
        if (index === TRAVERSAL_END) {
            (child as ByteSet).remove(bytes[index]);
        } else {
            (child as NumberSetNode).remove0(bytes, index, atWhichAllZero);
        }
    }

    protected *iterator(buf8: Uint8Array, buf64: Float64Array, offset: number): Generator<number> {
        if (this.value) {
            // Fill remaining bytes with 0 in case a previous iteration would have placed information in this area.
            // If this case is not triggered, a fill is not necessary since a complete overwrite is guaranteed.
            IS_BIG_ENDIAN ? buf8.fill(0, offset, 8) : buf8.fill(0, 0, offset + 1);
            yield buf64[0];
        }

        const next: number = offset + TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION;
        const isTail: boolean = next === TRAVERSAL_END;
        let child: NumberSetNode | ByteSet;
        for (let k of Object.keys(this.children)) {
            buf8[offset] = parseInt(k);
            child = this.children[k as unknown as number];
            if (isTail) {
                for (let n of (child as ByteSet).iterator(buf8, buf64, next)) yield n;
            } else {
                for (let n of (child as NumberSetNode).iterator(buf8, buf64, next)) yield n;
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * An iterable set that can contain any number representable in JS
 */
export class NumberSet extends NumberSetNode implements Iterable<number> {

    private readonly buf8: Uint8Array;
    private readonly buf64: Float64Array;
    private valueFlags: number = 0;

    constructor() {
        super();
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
        this.buf8 = new Uint8Array(buf);
        this.buf64 = new Float64Array(buf);
    }

    /**
     * NumberSet inherits has0, add0 and remove0 from NumberSetNode. This method converts a number
     * to the 3 arguments that those functions require: a Uint8Array containing the IEEE754 representation
     * of the number, an offset into the array that is significant for the current node, and an offset into the
     * array at which all further values are 0.
     */
    private parameterize(n: number): [ Uint8Array, number, number ] {
        if (isNaN(n)) throw new Error("Cannot add NaN to NumberSet");
        if (n === 0) n = 0; // JS says -0 === 0

        this.buf64[0] = n;
        let atWhichAllZero: number = TRAVERSAL_END + TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION;
        let i: number = atWhichAllZero;
        while (i !== TRAVERSAL_START) {
            i -= TRAVERSAL_DIRECTION;
            if (this.buf8[i] !== 0) break;
            atWhichAllZero = i;
        }
        return [ this.buf8, TRAVERSAL_START, atWhichAllZero ];
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the NumberSet contains the given number
     */
    has(n: number): boolean {
        return this.has0(...this.parameterize(n));
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given number to the NumberSet
     */
    add(n: number): void {
        if (n < 0) this.valueFlags |= 1; // Remember if this set may contain negative values
        if (n !== Math.trunc(n)) this.valueFlags |= 2; // Remember if this set may contain fractional values
        return this.add0(...this.parameterize(n));
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given number from the NumberSet
     */
    remove(n: number): void {
        return this.remove0(...this.parameterize(n));
    }

    /**
     * Clears the NumberSet
     */
    clear(): void {
        this.valueFlags = 0;
        this.clear0();
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
        return this.iterator(this.buf8, this.buf64, TRAVERSAL_START);
    }

    /**
     * Similar to ``Array.from(this)``, but is guaranteed to be efficiently sorted.
     */
    toArray(): number[] {
        /*
         * JS guarantees that numeric object keys will be sorted lexicographically. This allows us to take a shortcut.
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78731915/viable-to-sort-ieee754-floats-by-msb
         */
        let arr: Float64Array | number[];
        let typed: boolean;
        // We want to return a number[] always for API stability, but the code path for ``this.valueFlags & 1`` takes
        // advantage of efficient methods that only exist on Float64Array. So we keep track of whether or not the array
        // must be converted to a number[].
        if (this.valueFlags & 1) {
            arr = new Float64Array(this);
            if (arr.length < 2) return Array.from(arr);
            typed = true;

            // Negative values will appear after positive values during collection, flip them.
            let firstNegativeValue: number = (arr.length >> 1);
            let isNegative: boolean;
            while (true) {
                isNegative = arr[firstNegativeValue] < 0;
                if (isNegative) {
                    if (firstNegativeValue === 0) return Array.from(arr);
                    isNegative = arr[firstNegativeValue - 1] < 0;
                    if (!isNegative) break;
                    firstNegativeValue--;
                } else if ((++firstNegativeValue) >= arr.length) {
                    this.valueFlags ^= 1;
                    return Array.from(arr);
                }
            }
            const negativeValueCount: number = arr.length - firstNegativeValue;
            const positiveValues: Float64Array = arr.slice(0, firstNegativeValue);
            arr.copyWithin(0, firstNegativeValue, arr.length);
            if (negativeValueCount > 1) arr.subarray(0, negativeValueCount).reverse();
            arr.set(positiveValues, negativeValueCount);
        } else {
            arr = Array.from(this);
            if (arr.length < 2) return arr;
            typed = false;
        }
        if (this.valueFlags & 2) {
            // This shortcut may not work for some fractional numbers, sort if not already sorted.
            let last: number = arr[0];
            let cur: number;
            for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                cur = arr[i];
                if (cur < last) {
                    arr = arr.sort();
                    break;
                }
                last = cur;
            }
        }
        return typed ? Array.from(arr) : arr as number[];
    }

}

EDIT: Post is outdated, you can see the latest iteration of the code on a GitHub repository here

Wouldn't you like to share some /* comments */ with us which describe key interface Specifications and internal Data Structures? Maybe an automated test suite? As written, it is unclear why an engineer would choose to use the OP library code, nor how they would test that the Right Thing happened after calling into it.

@J_H I agree that this code may have been posted prematurely. This is part of a larger, currently unpublished library which will have a test suite and comments. That is why I mentioned how this code ended up here, and why I intend to update this post as I improve it.

These add and remove:

add(index: number): void {
    this.set(index, true);
}

remove(index: number): void {
    this.set(index, false);
}

private set(index: number, value: boolean): void {
    const flag = 1 << (index & 7);
    index >>= 3;
    if (value) {
        this.data[index] |= flag;
    } else {
        this.data[index] &= (~flag);
    }
}


Build something simple on top of something complicated: making a bit 1 or making a bit 0, are both simpler (if implemented by themselves, without depending on set) than "writing" an arbitrary bit into a bit-array. In general I think you should avoid that. It's a kind of "abstraction inversion".

for fun of course, I have no idea if this is performant

It's a kind of trie that uses bit-arrays at the leafs, that can be good. You can do more tricks with them than you've shown. For example, given two of these sets, you can compute their union or intersection or symmetric difference more efficiently than going element-by-element, by relying on bitwise operations between the bit-arrays in the leafs (you could likely do this more efficiently based on an Int32Array).
Some other operations, such as finding the smallest element, smallest element greater than some given number, could be implemented efficiently if you wanted to do that.
You can do "sparse iteration" (jumping over unset bits) when iterating over the elements in the set: instead of testing every bit, calculate the trailing zero count to jump directly to the first set bit, and use a bitmath trick to unset that bit (this also works better if you're working with int32 instead of bytes). Note that while TZCNT is not a built-in, there is clz32 in the JS Math api and it's easy to use LZCNT to implement TZCNT: tzcnt(x) == lzcnt(x & -x) ^ 31 except when x == 0, and that is a case that doesn't matter here since the inner loop only runs while there are set bits left to iterate over.

I did update the iterator to skip 4 bytes at a time using Uint32Array earlier today, and I have historically used clz32 to identify set bits, but I was unsure of whether or not using that here would be worth it. The blog post you linked is insightful, thanks.

I'm afraid I do not yet see the motivation for this code.
Raw floats are commonly serialized in hexadecimal format.
Stripping trailing hex zeros, to give shorter strings,
seems like it would go at least part way to satisfying
some of the goals of this code.
A suite of unit tests could carry much of the teaching burden.
helpful comments
Thank you for these:
/**
 * A simple set that can contain values from 0 to 255 (inclusive).
 */
        ...
        // 256 bits can fit in 32 bytes

When I initially read the public methods, without comments, I found that the
magic number
of 32 was on the obscure side.
Now it is perfectly clear.
None of the public methods explain their range
pre-condition,
but maybe the class TSDoc suffices for that.
Do consider adding an assert which enforces the input range,
to guard against potential buggy callers not realizing they
have gone astray.
meaningful identifier
I take this to be more of a single-bit mask than a boolean flag:
    has(index: number): boolean {
        const flag = 1 << (index & 7);
        return (this.data[index >> 3] & flag) !== 0;
    }

As written, this seems like low level embedded code,
which might access one of several hardware register flags
that all appear together at a single memory location.
And I still find the datastructure obscure,
despite the initial comment of several sentences.
I wish that comment spoke of "prefixes" which
end in all zeros.
Then the clunky atWhichAllZero could be prefixLength.
I suspect the documentation should probably include an ASCII art picture
of an IEEE double (sign, exponent, significand)
and how a JS number fits into that.
And a separate picture showing a ByteSet and at least one NumberSetNode.
BTW the endian and traversal stuff is crystal clear, thank you.
I guess you have some embedded or DSP target in mind,
since to a fair approximation "everything is little endian" these days.
I love my Motorola 68040 NeXT, but it's quite a while since
last I powered it on.
Instead of if conditionals, you might have chosen to
send all array references through one more level of indirection.
For one endianness it would be an 8-element identity function,
and for the other it would be the reverse of that.
any number
This is lovely:
/**
 * An iterable set that can contain any number representable in JS
 */

But I wonder if it is completely accurate?
Or if we'd maybe like to scope it down slightly.
I'm willing to agree that NaN does not fit into
the set of "any number".
But then there's the infinities.
And we clearly don't store negative zero, as there's a line of
code which adjusts its sign.
named flags
I imagine we're storing both flags in a single variable
for some goal like saving memory. Ok, fine.
        if (n < 0) this.valueFlags |= 1; // Remember if this set may contain negative values
        if (n !== Math.trunc(n)) this.valueFlags |= 2; // Remember if this set may contain fractional values

But instead of 1 and 2 with associated comments,
please name those bits.
Also, I find "may contain" regrettably wishy washy.
If each flag was a counter,
then remove() could decrement to fix things up upon removal.
When computing firstNegativeValue it's not obvious to me
why half the array length is of interest.
And the while (true) loop variants are obscure,
so the exit condition is unclear.
The valueFlags & 2 codepath looks dodgy.
Like much of this code,
it would benefit from being exercised by an automated test suite.

I would not be willing to maintain this codebase in its current form,
as I have not yet adequately understood its datastructures and logic.

Thanks for the thoughtful comments! I will take that into consideration, especially counting the number of negative values rather than having a flag. I was able to remove the valueFlags & 2 code path entirely (and verify that it was safe to do so with unit tests), so a counter will take it's place nicely.
